# Export and edit work items in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, export, devops, workitem

I have a problem with exporting and customizing work items in Azure DevOps
when I try to export work items I get this error "The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator. process ID x Project ID x."
I'm the only user in azure DevOps
I tried with tftp tools and witadmin command and both errors were the same.
can anyone help me

Notice: I use Azure DevOps On-premise

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to export work items I get this error "The feature is
> disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator. process ID x
> Project ID x

To achieve the above requirement ,

***As you are user,
First of all you need to have an administrator permissions to your project***.
*Then we can export the project .*

Based on this Prequisite as described on [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops) well: -

[image]

**To get those permissions you can refer this** [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-organization-collection-level-permissions?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=preview-page).

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=azure-devops-2020#import-and-export-work-item-type-definition-files)

Comment: thanx for your reaction 
but I did both of them and it didn't work
and I'm even a member of the administrator of the collection 
but I give this error 
also, I test with the process editor on visual studio 2019 but nothing changed 
I don't know where is my problem and that make me crazy 
do you have any idea???